# How to login into a sandbox from Sandboxes page in Production org?

Tags: sandbox

We are able to login as a system administrator into the production org of one of our client. The client has sent his own credentials which he used to login. Now we are planning to use the Dev sandbox which is already available in the prod org.

The issue is when we click the login link it opens the login page and prompt me to enter password. the username is already populated suffixed with the sandbox name. i entered the same password which i used it for the prod org but not able to login got incorrect username or password. What would be the issue?

Please note the sandbox which already exists in the client prod org was created by someone else.

Do i need to refresh the sandbox in order to login with the current user credentials which i am using in production org?

[image]

Comment: what is the user name that you are using to login, usually we use username.sandboxname and password as the PRD passowrd. Users can log into the sandbox at https://test.salesforce.com by appending .sandbox_name to their Salesforce usernames. For example, if a username for a production organization is user1@acme.com, and the sandbox is named “test”, then the modified username to log into the sandbox is user1@acme.com.test.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Take a look at this document :

https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=data_sandbox_create.htm&language=en_US

> Users can log into the sandbox at https://test.salesforce.com by
>   appending .sandbox_name to their Salesforce usernames. For example, if
>   a username for a production organization is user1@acme.com, and the
>   sandbox is named “test”, then the modified username to log into the
>   sandbox is user1@acme.com.test.
>
> **> Note Salesforce automatically changes sandbox usernames, but not
>   passwords.**

Comment: How about SSO enabled login from production?