# Can't login to sandbox, followed other thread advices, still can't get in

Tags: sandbox, appexchange, login

I am logged into production.
Trying to install (Box) from AppExchange into a sandbox.
I can't get logged into the sandbox, though.
It prepopulated Username, but my password isn't working.

I've tried a dozen different permutations of credentials following the advice of several threads here (notably, [How to login into a sandbox from Sandboxes page in Production org?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/31543/how-to-login-into-a-sandbox-from-sandboxes-page-in-production-org)).

I've been trying to log in for a full hour and I'm no closer...

Comment: why don't you just click on Forgot password in Sandbox login page and reset the password. may be somechanged it

Comment: are you sure the URL in the address bar is test.salesforce.com ?

Comment: Was trying to log in from production, but also tried test.salesforce.com with the sandbox name after my username  xxx@ccc.com.box

Comment: it is a brand new, fresh, unlogged-into sandbox

Comment: Has the sandbox been completed already? It's not still pending creation?

Comment: It is completed, yes. I initially wsa trying to log in from the production link, then tried test.salesforce.com

Answer (score 1):

Okay, this problem was that the sandboxes had been completed, but were not activated.

For future readers: You can check the 'auto activate' box when creating, else you'll get an email with a link to click to activate the sandbox.